# Storing additional information about celery tasks in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I want to store in MongoDB additional information about a task. For example, an ID of a user that created the task.

```
{
  "_id" : "a77db490-d090-4c9d-a48c-b6f766bee902",
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "result" : "8",
  "date_done" : ISODate("2017-11-17T10:16:28.942Z"),
  "traceback" : "null",
  "children" : "[]",
  "task_creator": "username" // <---- How can I add such field?
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass `task_creator` as an argument to your function. Since it is sent as an argument to your task, it will be there in `args` parameter, even though you won't use this in your task.